# Boolean method that passes in instance of object giving error for return statement

Tags: java, object, methods, boolean, return

I'm making a blackjack game and I'm making a method to see if a player has an ace or not.

```
public static boolean hasAce(Player player){
        for (int j=0; j<player.getNumOfCards();j++){
            int cardValue = player.getCard(j).getValue();
            if (cardValue == 1){
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Okay so it's giving me an error that it must return a type boolean, but I am. It looks like it wants the return statement at the bottom, but that's not possible if I need to have an if else statement.

PS. The code may be troubling to read because these are my own methods but basically `if (cardValue == 1)` then there is an ace and the for loop is just cycling through the cards the player has.

Comment: What's the point of having a for-loop if you'll return on the first iteration ?

Answer (score 3):

The compiler cannot determine that the for loop is guaranteed to be run, hence it complains. There is also an additional problem. Your for loop only ever iterates once, as it always returns after checking only the first card. You can change it to:

```
public static boolean hasAce(Player player) {
    boolean returnValue = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < player.getNumOfCards(); j++) {
        int cardValue = player.getCard(j).getValue();
        if (cardValue == 1) {
            returnValue = true;
            break;
        } 
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

This will now break as soon as an ace is found. Otherwise it will check every card in the hand, and if no ace is found returnValue will still be false.

Comment: No brother, you're making this bad code even worse... see my other comment above.